# Routing diffent url(which are not define in web.xml) to same jsp

Tags: java, xml, jsp

I am working in jsp and this is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Panel</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>

  </welcome-file-list>

 <servlet>
          <servlet-name>dash.jsp</servlet-name>
          <jsp-file>/dash.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>dash.jsp</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/dash.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

So if user types /dash.jsp in browser it will redirected to dash.jsp

My problem is that if a user types any other url which is not defined in web.xml it should be forwarded to one specific page(permission_denied.jsp)

Any help would be appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an error mapping in the web.xml for error code 404 too your page.

<error-page><error-code>404</error-code><location>/permission_denied.jsp</location></error-page>

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using default mapping (since Servlet 3.0):

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

or using error page mapped to Not Found error code (404):

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/default.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```